# Extending generic class in Kotlin

Tags: java, generics, kotlin

Lets say that I have this sample code in Java:

```
public class MyActivityDelegate implements ActivityMvpDelegate
```

where ActivityMvpDelegate:

```
interface ActivityMvpDelegate<V extends MvpView, P extends MvpPresenter<V>>
```

Same code converted to Kotlin looks like this

```
class MyActivityDelegate(private val activity: Activity) : ActivityMvpDelegate<MvpView, MvpPresenter<V>>
```

Of course I got unresolved reference at `V` and I'm not sure how this code should looks, in Java I don't have to specify generic over here.. any tips gonna be much appreciated

Comment: Your java sample `public class MyActivityDelegate implements ActivityMvpDelegate` looks incomplete (it will not compile either), are you sure that's the exact declaration of `MyActivityDelegate` ?

Comment: Yes it is, and yes, it compiles

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your interface declaration requires that

- `V` extends `MvpView`
- `V` (exactly `V`, not its subtype) is used as generic parameter for `P extends MvpPresenter<V>`

Given that, you cannot extend `ActivityMvpDelegate<MvpView, MvpPresenter<V>>`, because there's no guarantee that `V` is exactly `MvpView` (also, in Kotlin, generic parameters are not implicitly inherited, you have to redeclarate them like `class SomeClass<T> : SomeInterface<T>`).

You can, however, write it as

```
class MyActivityDelegate(private val activity: Activity) 
: ActivityMvpDelegate<MvpView, MvpPresenter<MvpView>>
```

or introduce another generic parameter, so that `V` and the argument for `P` are still the same:

```
class MyActivityDelegate<T : MvpView>(private val activity: Activity) 
: ActivityMvpDelegate<T, MvpPresenter<T>>
```

You can also change the generic declaration of your interface from `P extends MvpPresenter<V>` to `P extends MvpPresenter<? extends V>` (or use [`out V`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#use-site-variance-type-projections) in Kotlin), and you will be able to use any subtype of `V` as the argument, including bounded generic:

```
class MyActivityDelegate<T : MvpView>(private val activity: Activity) 
: ActivityMvpDelegate<MvpView, MvpPresenter<T>>
```